# PHP from address issue in mailing

Tags: php

below is my code ,i got from address as web admin's mail id

```
   <?php

    $headers = 'From: '."raji@nexegen.net"."\r\n";
    $headers = 'BCC: '."raji@nexegen.net"."\r\n";

    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

    $mail_status = mail("raji@nexegen.net", "hii", "nothing", $headers);
     ?>
```

Comment: And what is the question.?

Comment: from address should be raji@nexegen.net since it is added  as from in header.but in my inbox it shows the domain id

Comment: @User016 How many email header injection security holes does it have? Cos depending where $email comes from, I got one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want this. Note change to 2nd line

```
<?php

    $headers = 'From: '."raji@nexegen.net"."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'BCC: '."raji@nexegen.net"."\r\n";

    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

    $mail_status = mail("raji@nexegen.net", "hii", "nothing", $headers);
     ?>
```

Comment: In case anyone else happens across this and isn't sure what this means - the 2nd line left the dot out. $headers = will overwrite the $headers variable. $headers .= will add to the variable since . is a concatenation operator in php

Comment: :) thank u very much.i was in a hurry

Answer (score 3):

Forgot the string append concatenation operator (.):

`$headers .= 'BCC: '."raji@nexegen.net"."\r\n";`